# DataGridView.CellValueChanged not firing on bound DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview, datatable

When I change a value programatically in a DataTable that my DataGridView is bound to, the appropriate CellValueChanged event is not firing for the DataGridView. I'm trying to change a cell's background color based on cell value when the DataTable is filled with data without iterating through every row and checking each value.

Answer (score 2):

You are changing the `DataTable` directly and expect `DataGridView`'s event to be fired?
I suggest that you change the cell value programatically as:

```
DataGridView[ColumnIndex, RowIndex].Value = NewValue;
```

Additionally you will have to Call `DataGridView.CommitEdit()` to commit the values to the `DataTable`. This should trigger the `CellValueChanged` event.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellvaluechanged.aspx

Comment: Yes I expect it to fire. The value displayed in the cell is changing.

Comment: CellValueChanged event only fires when a new value is pushed from the DGV to the DT. Not other way round.

Comment: I don't mind the down votes, but a reason will certainly help.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the cells background color should be done in the RowPrePaint-Event, this will be fired if the row is repainted, after the value change.