# DataGridView.CellValueChanged not firing for data-bound DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, datagridview

Although there are many similar questions were asked before, but i didn't find suitable answer :(. e.g. [Similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580269/datagridview-cellvaluechanged-not-firing-on-bound-datagridview)

My `DataGridView.Cellvalues` changes as per databounded source programatically. I would like to track sum of certain columns, but  `DataGridView.CellValueChanged` event is only applicable when cell has focus(not it case it changed programatically). I dont want to use `RowPrePaint` Event , or `CellPainting` events because of performance reason.

Is there any suitable events or approach?

Comment: Have you tried the `DataSourceChanged` event?

Comment: yes, I tried DataSourceChanged event  doesnot get raised :(

Comment: It certainly gets raised under the right conditions, but we cannot guess what are your exact conditions. Please, post a relevant part of your code describing what you mean with "per databounded source programatically".

Comment: @varocarbas Here is the sample code 
`BindingList<ClassA> Items = new BindingList<ClassA>();`

`DataGridView1.DataSource=SomeObject.Items;`

Comment: Firstly, you should edit your question rather than writing a comment such that everyone can immediately understand the whole situation. Secondly, this code doesn't make too much sense. Why don't you keep it simple just to understand what is going wrong? A code working for sure: `DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add("Col 1");
dt.Rows.Add("1");
dt.Rows.Add("2");
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;` You don't have always to rely on `DataTable` to set the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`, but it is the simplest/always-working option which will surely trigger the aforementioned event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem and solved it using the DataBindingComplete event.

For working with certain columns only, this should perform well for you as I believe it's only called once after data binding operations are complete.

You will need to do your own iteration through the grid as required as the DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs obviously does not have the RowIndex and ColumnIndex properties, but you can do something like this:

```
private void DataGridView1_DataBindingComplete(object sender, DataGridViewBindingCompleteEventArgs e)
{
    var senderGrid = (DataGridView)sender;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in senderGrid.Rows)
    {
        // Determine the bound data object for the current row
        var currentRowObj = row.DataBoundItem;

        // Access the data in a particular cell on this row
        var cellToTotal = row.Cells["Column1"];

        etc
    }
}
```